# Question Regarding Vectors

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, vectors, geometry

In Newtonian Mechanics, we use mathematical vectors to model quantities that have a notion called "direction" associated with them. The length of the vector is modelled to represent the size of the quantity. (An acceleration of $5m/s^{2}$ can be represented as a vector of $5$ units). I can only understand this as a way of mere notation, or geometrical representation.

However, in Newtonian Mechanics, it is a strategy to analyze a vector by "breaking it down" into its vector components. This, as I have been long taught, is done by considering the vectors mathematical feature of having a length, and given the direction of the vector (the angle it makes with the horizontal), we can trigonometrically consider the vector as two vector components that have different directions, but their vector sum gives us our previous vector.

However, this is where I am lost in quandary. How do we justify the fact that we can actually use the vectors in their mathematical sense? How do we know that acceleration is a  mathematical length? So far we have only represented it as a length for pure demonstration, but when we actually start using properties that are exclusive to lengths only, we must be sure that acceleration really is a length (with direction; a vector). I understand Newton is very fond of Euclid's deductive treatise, that is, the Element's of Euclid; but how does Newton justify the fact that we can think of quantities with a direction as actual mathematical lengths?

Comment: Vectors were not used by Newton. They only became popular in the late 1800's

Comment: Re, "How do we know that acceleration is a mathematical length?" Acceleration is not length—not according to the _usual_ meaning of "length." But you said, "mathematical length." What is that? Are you speaking of the _magnitude_ of the acceleration vector? Some people describe vectors as "arrows" with "length" and direction. "Length," "magnitude," Whatever! It's an abstract idea that we employ to represent physical quantities like acceleration, velocity, distance, electric potential, etc., etc., etc.

Comment: Re, "breaking it down into it's vector components." A vector, _per se,_ does not have components. The idea of components only comes in to play when we define a _coordinate system._ The purpose of a coordinate system is to allow us to assign numerical values to the vectors in some problem. But, for any given problem, there are infinitely many different coordinate systems that we could choose. (Some of which are a better fit to the problem than others.) A vector's "components" depend on which coordinate system you choose for the problem. By itself, it has no _natural_ components.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean! How do we know that we can represent acceleration as a vector? Because in order for us to work trigonometry with it, we would require that acceleration actually is a vector.

Comment: I get that you can represent acceleration, speed, forces with vectors. But the problem is when we use these vectors mathematically. For example, when we break a force vector into it's vector components. Lets say we have a force of $10N$ at an angle $30°$ with the horizontal. Then the magnitudes of the vector components are $10sin30°$ (up/down) and $10cos30°$ (left/right). We broke the vector into it's components using trigonometry, that is we considered it as an actual length. How can we do that if it's not really a length?

Comment: Why do you say that the component vectors do not represent a length?  The mathematics of vectors does a good job representing certain physical quantities.  Is that not enough justification?

Answer (score 2):

So we will focus mainly on why these vector quantities such as velocity, acceleration, forces etc. follow mathematical geometry rules as they are only valid for our normal lengths. As I found this the more crucial part of this question, So I would answer this in the way that if we take an example of velocity the simple definition tells us everything, i.e the amount of displacement the object is undergoing per unit time in some specific direction. Also now we will have to admit the fact that this word **displacement** is a vector quantity and **also follows mathematical geometry**, if you just draw the position vectors from one point to another, then you can easily calculate the change in position vector by using simple mathematical geometry i.e it is actually a length so it will have to follow **mathematical geometry**.

Now since velocity is just change in position vector for a unit time, then this will also follow the rules as displacement follows because **velocity** can also be thought as the **displacement** for a unit time. Or if we write $\frac{ds}{dt}=c$, That means the object is making $ds$ displacement in $dt$ amount of time. So this is how it become pretty obvious to think that why should vector quantities follow the geometrical rules. (And also Note that this is only the analogy to think why the vector quantities actually follows mathematical geometry, and velocity and displacement are actually two very different quantities so do not confuse).

Comment: Hold on, I understand that we can represent vector quantities, say speed, using vectors purely for demonstration. But what about when we use trigonometry to find its vector components? In order for us to be able to use trigonometry, we would need to actually requirement that speed is a vector in a purely mathematical sense!

Comment: @Camelot823 so I guess further you mean that why these quantities I.e acceleration, velocity etc. follows mathematical geometry yes?

Comment: Yes, exactly! That is my question.

Comment: @Camelot823 OK, I made an edit to my post to answer for the same. Hope you will get your answer from this now.

Answer (score 0):

Physics is a tool to describe the behavior of the universe. Physics is not the universe itself. There are different versions of physics - Classical, special relativity, quantum mechanics, general relativity, etc. Each describes a piece of the behavior. All are approximate to some degree. We don't even know the total behavior. All are pretty good.

So an acceleration is not a little arrow. It has a magnitude, a size. But that size is not a length.

Still, a little arrow is a useful tool to describe accelerations. Little arrows add like accelerations. Two opposing arrows add to $0$. So do two opposing accelerations.

For components, you can take any arrow in any direction and find 3 arrows that add up to it, where one is parallel to the x axis, one to the y axis, and one to the z axis. You can break down any acceleration in a similar way using accelerations parallel to the axes. Little arrows act so much like vectors that we often think about them interchangeably.

---

Little arrows are presented as vectors so much that people start to think of them as the definition of a vector. But the definition of a vector space is a set of objects that behave according to 8 mathematical rules when added together and multiplied by numbers. These rules just spell out reasonable behavior for addition and multiplication. Things like

$$(\vec A + \vec B) + \vec C = \vec A + (\vec B + \vec C)$$

So little arrows are a vector space because they fit the definition.

Many things in physics that have a direction also do this and are easy to match up to arrows. So accelerations also fit the definition of a vector space.

---

The idea that things with a magnitude and direction are vectors is not always correct. There are some counter examples.

First, consider the set of all quadratic equations $y = ax^2 + bx + c$. You can add two quadratic equations together and get a quadratic equation. You can multiply one by a number and get a quadratic equation. You can prove addition follows the associative law, and all the other rules of vector spaces. The set of quadratic equations is a vector space. But a given quadratic equation has no obvious direction.

Kinetic energy is another counter example. It does have a magnitude and direction. But it isn't a vector. It doesn't add right. Two balls flying toward each other at high speed do not have a total kinetic energy of $0$.

Comment: But what about when we use trigonometry to break a force vector into it's vector components? We wouldn't be able to do that if the force vector wasn't an actual vector in the mathematical sense. Because trigonometrical laws only apply to mathematical lengths and vectors.

Comment: A force is a vector. Force and little arrows are very much alike in that they described by a magnitude and direction. You can match up any force with the corresponding arrow, and vice versa. This allows you to do trigonometry indirectly on forces. For each force, you find the matching arrow. You do trig on the arrows. You go back to the forces. This is complicated to think about, but it works.

Comment: This is why people take a mental shortcut. They think about a force as if it was an arrow. Then doing trig on forces is the same thing as doing it on arrows. People get so used to this that they think about forces as arrows, and forget any difference.

Comment: But you are right to take the difference seriously. There is a branch of mathematics devoted to vector spaces and similar things. There are differences between how mathematicians and physicists think about vector spaces that you will get to in more advanced courses. There are more complex versions of vector spaces called tensor spaces. These are used all over general relativity, and have uses in advanced mechanics. Keeping in mind what is math and what is physics can be useful. But taking mental shortcuts can too, especially if you understand why and how they work.

Answer (score 0):

Given an euclidean space, we can assign a vector to each pair of points. The vectors are elements of a vector space $W$. You are right that velocities are not elements of $W$, but fixing a unit of time allows us to identify each velocity with a vector in $W$:

Let $V$ be the set of all velocities and $U$ the set of all units of time. Given $v\in V$ and $u\in U$, let $vu$ be the displacement of an object with velocity $v$ in time $u$. This defines a function$$V\times U\to W$$and for each $u\in U$ the function
\begin{align}
V&\to W\\
v&\mapsto vu
\end{align}
is bijective.